# jquery - toggle visibility of divs inside a div

Tags: jquery, toggle, visibility

I got a problem with a jQuery function.

#### Situation

I got one div, containing a list of `<input type="radio" />` elements. These should remote control the visibility of the other two divs. The first radio input field should show the first div when checked, the other ones should a) the second div and b) only one of the divs inside the second div.

#### Problem

The display (show/hide toggle) between the first & second main divs works fine. What doesn't work is the toggling the visibility state of the divs inside the second div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready( function($)
        {
            $( "#post_format_box" ).addClass( "hidden" );

            $( "input#post-format-0" ).change( function() {
                $( "#postdivrich" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
                $( "#post_format_box" ).addClass( "hidden" );
            } );

            $( "input:not(#post-format-0)" ).change( function() {
                $( "#postdivrich" ).addClass( "hidden" );
                $( "#post_format_box" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
            } );

            $( "#post-format-aside" ).change( function() {
                $( "#aside" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
            } );
            $( "#post-format-audio" ).change( function() {
                $( "#audio" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
            } );
            $( "#post-format-chat" ).change( function() {
                $( "#chat" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
            } );
            $( "#post-format-gallery" ).change( function() {
                $( "#gallery" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
            } );
            $( "#post-format-image" ).change( function() {
                $( "#image" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
            } );
            $( "#post-format-link" ).change( function() {
                $( "#link" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
            } );
            $( "#post-format-quote" ).change( function() {
                $( "#quote" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
            } );
            $( "#post-format-status" ).change( function() {
                $( "#status" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
            } );
            $( "#post-format-video" ).change( function() {
                $( "#video" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
            } );
        }
    );
</script>
```

The divs look like this:

```
<div id="formatdiv">
<!-- REMOTE CONTROLING DIV -->
    <!-- SHOWS/HIDES THE #postdivricht -->
    <input type="radio" class="post-format-0" checked="checked" />

    <!-- THESE SHOW/HIDE THE SINGLE DIVS INSIDE #postdivricht -->
    <input type="radio" id="post-format-aside" />
    <input type="radio" id="post-format-audio" />
    <input type="radio" id="post-format-chat" />
    <input type="radio" id="post-format-gallery" />
    <input type="radio" id="post-format-image" />
    <input type="radio" id="post-format-link" />
    <input type="radio" id="post-format-quote" />
    <input type="radio" id="post-format-status" />
    <input type="radio" id="post-format-video" />
</div>

<div id="postdivrich">
    <!-- FIRST REMOTE CONTROLED DIV -->
</div>

<div id="post_format_box">
    <!-- SECOND REMOTE CONTROLED DIV -->
    <div id="aside">
        <p>Aside</p>
    </div>
    <div id="audio">
        <p>Audio</p>
    </div>
    <div id="chat">
        <p>Chat</p>
    </div>
    <div id="gallery">
        <p>Gallery</p>
    </div>
    <div id="image">
        <p>Image</p>
    </div>
    <div id="link">
        <p>Link</p>
    </div>
    <div id="quote">
        <p>Quote</p>
    </div>
    <div id="status">
        <p>Status</p>
    </div>
    <div id="video">
        <p>Video</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a particular reason your using add/remove class instead of show hide?

Comment: @Patrick: No, there isn't. I just don't know javascript and trying to get around. Alternate solutions using show/hide also appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

(Also, assuming [because of the Radio buttons] that you only want 1 of those visible at a time)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NVGvc/)**

Ditch all of the individual `.change()` functions for this:

```
$("input[name=post-format]").click(function() {
    var mydiv = $(this).attr('class').replace('post-format-','');
    $("#post_format_box div").addClass("hidden");
    $("#post_format_box div#"+mydiv).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

**Please Note:** I've added the `name` attribute to your Radio buttons.

Comment: Too bad i can't upvote more than +1. Thanks for the example and anything. If someone reads that later: I updated the Q from .class to #ID, so the live demo would need to have **a)** the `input[type="radio"]` classes exchanged by id selectors and **b)** the jQuery function above (from @jnpcl) would need to change `.attr('class')` to `.attr('id')`.

Comment: @kaiser: Upvoted comments don't grant rep.. but an Accepted Answer gives +15.

Answer (score 2):

all your code in the html is using classes, wherein all the code in the js is using ids:

change the lines like thi, for example:

```
   $( "#post-format-status" ).change( function() {
            $( "#status" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
        } );
```

**BECOMES:**

```
    $( ".post-format-status" ).change( function() {
            $( "#status" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
        } );
```

also use checkboxes not radio's for toggles

Comment: Sorry, it's a simplyfied example and i just wrote it wrong. See updated answer classes changed to IDs.

Answer (score 1):

try [`$("#postdivrich").show();`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`$("#postdivrich").hide();`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

if you want to get fancy you can do [`$("#postdivrich").fadeIn(600);`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`$("#postdivrich").fadeOut(600);`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Or, you could go even use [`$.fadeToggle();`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)